# How do i get "show more" button to show the rest of array item/component

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm trying to implement a show more button to my code. but i don't know how to do it in vue, have been search for the solution but still not find it.
At default it's supose to display 9 item and when click "show more" it will show the rest of the items

```
import { ref } from "vue";

const card = 9;
const step = 5;

function visibleCard() {
  return this.cards.slice(0, this.cardVisible);
}

const cards = ref([
  { key: 1, judul: "Frontend"},
  { key: 2, judul: "Backend"},
  { key: 3, judul: "UI/UX"},
  { key: 4, judul: "Product Manager"},
  { key: 5, judul: "Product Manager"},
]);
```

```
<div class="collaps" v-for="card in cards.slice(0, this.limit)">
  <button @click="cardVisible += step" v-if="cardVisible < cards.length">
    Show more
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you getting all items at once or else you are triggering an api to load to next `n` values?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a computed function that takes care of slicing the data. You also need a variable to set the total length.

Another note is that you have "show more" button inside the v-for loop. I am not sure if this is the intended behaviour as it will create a button for each item. I think you want to create a button for the whole group.

Here is your code with the modification:

```
<template>
  <div class="collaps" v-for="card in getCards">
    <div>{{ card }}</div>
  </div>

  <button
    @click="currentStep = currentStep + stepBy"
    v-if="currentStep < total"
  >
    Show more
  </button>
</template>
```

and js:

```
<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue';
const stepBy = 5;

const currentStep = ref(5);
const total = ref(9);

const cards = ref([
  { key: 1, judul: 'Frontend' },
  { key: 2, judul: 'Backend' },
  { key: 3, judul: 'UI/UX' },
  { key: 4, judul: 'Product Manager' },
  { key: 5, judul: 'Product Manager' },
  { key: 6, judul: 'test1' },
  { key: 7, judul: 'test2' },
  { key: 8, judul: 'test3' },
  { key: 9, judul: 'test3' },
]);

const getCards = computed(() => {
  return cards.value.slice(0, currentStep.value);
});
```

Comment: okay that work, then how do i change "show more" to "show less" ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your method

```js
showless() {
this.limit = 9
}
```

```html
edit your buttons
<button @click="showless" v-if="(this.limit === this.cards.length - 1)">showless</button>
<button @click="showmore" v-else>show more</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

**add this line,**

```
const limit = 9;
```

**edit these lines**

```
v-for="card in cards.slice(0, this.limit)"

<button @click="showMore">show more </button>
```

**add this function to method**

```
showMore() {
    this.limit = this.cards.length - 1
}
```

Comment: it's said ""limit" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance."

Comment: because you have defined the card to be 9 but not the limit, you should change const card to const limit..

Comment: const limit = 9;
function showMore() {
  this.limit = this.cards.length - 1;
}

<div class="collaps" v-for="card in cards.slice(0, this.limit)">
      <button @click="showMore">Show more</button>
    </div>

why the button looping untill 11 ?

Comment: That's because the button is in the for-loop div( you have to move the button outside the v-for div)

const limit = 9; 
function showMore() { 
this.limit = this.cards.length - 1;
 } 
<div class="collaps" v-for="card in cards.slice(0, this.limit)">
put the images or the elements you want to repeat
</div>

 <button @click="showMore">Show more</button>

Comment: thanks mate, it work for "show more" and now how can i change to "show less" ?

Comment: I have edited the first code , to add the showless button. you can refer